# Spring boot multiple external datasource stored in internal database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot project and I have one internal database with the configuration on the application.properties. In this database I have a Company table which contains the connection informations to external databases (all the external databases have same structure).

I created a class which create datasource when we need :

```
public class PgDataSource {

    private static Map<Long, DataSource> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();

    private static void createDataSource(Company company) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(1);
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://"+company.getUrl()+"/"+company.getIdClient());
        hikariConfig.setUsername(company.getUsername());
        hikariConfig.setPassword(company.getPassword());

        dataSourceMap.put(company.getId(), new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig));
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource(Company company) {
        if (!dataSourceMap.containsKey(company.getId()))
            createDataSource(company);

        return dataSourceMap.get(company.getId());
    }

}
```

Could you tell me if this solution is the best and if I can use JPA with this solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in your setup is not multiple datasources, but the fact that they are dynamic, i.e. determined at run time.
In addition to a `DataSource` JPA uses `EntityManagerFactory` and `TransactionManager`, which are determined statically i.e. at compile time. So it's not easy to use JPA with dynamic data sources.

In Spring Boot 2 you can try the [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html), which allows to route JPA calls to a different datasource based on some (thread-bound) context. [Here's](http://kimrudolph.de/blog/spring-datasource-routing) an example of how it can be used and a [demo](https://github.com/krudolph/spring-datasource-routing) application.

Alternatively you can turn your setup into a static setup, then use the regular [multiple datasource](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7) approach. The downside is that the list of "companies" will be fixed at compile time, and so is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it's work fine !

My solution :

I create a first datasource for my local database with [@Primary](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "localEntityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"fr.axygest.akostaxi.local"}
)
public class LocalConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "localEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("fr.axygest.akostaxi.local.model")
                .persistenceUnit("local")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("localEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Next, for the x external databases save in the company table of the local database, I use [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html)

I store a current context as a ThreadLocal :

```
public class ThreadPostgresqlStorage {

    private static ThreadLocal<Long> context = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setContext(Long companyId) {
        context.set(companyId);
    }

    public static Long getContext() {
        return context.get();
    }

}
```

I defined the RoutingSource to extend the [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) :

```
public class RoutingSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource
{
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return ThreadPostgresqlStorage.getContext();
    }

}
```

And the config class create all the databases connection saved in company table :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"fr.axygest.akostaxi.postgresql"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "pgEntityManager"
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PgConfig {

    private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PgConfig(CompanyRepository companyRepository) {
        this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
    }

    @Bean(name = "pgDataSource")
    public DataSource pgDataSource() {
        RoutingSource routingSource = new RoutingSource();
        List<Company> companies = companyRepository.findAll();
        HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>(companies.size());
        companies.forEach(company -> {
            map.put(company.getId(), createDataSource(company));
        });
        routingSource.setTargetDataSources(map);
        routingSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return routingSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "pgEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean pgEntityManager(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("pgDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("fr.axygest.akostaxi.postgresql.model")
                .persistenceUnit("pg")
                .properties(jpaProperties())
                .build();
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource(Company company) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(1);
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + company.getUrl() + "/" + company.getIdClient());
        hikariConfig.setUsername(company.getUsername());
        hikariConfig.setPassword(company.getPassword());

        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return props;
    }

}
```